# In-Proc DB supporting sprocs

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures

Is there an in process database, like SQLite or Sql Server Compact Edition, that supports stored procedures?

Answer (score 1):

Consider evaluating [TurboDB](http://www.dataweb.de/en/products/dotnet_database.html) for your needs. Features from its website.

> TurboDB Managed is an SQL database for .NET Framework and .NET Compact Framework written entirely in C#. At run-time it consists of a single assembly that is simply copied to the target system.

TurboDB supports:

- a large SQL feature set
- running DDL statements
- transactions
- stored procedures

The vendor has a [comparison chart against other similar databases](http://www.dataweb.de/en/products/comparison_dotnet_databases.html).

Answer (score 1):

[H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)

[Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)

[HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)

All three are written in Java.